# NSLocalizedString, change language based on application preference

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nslocalizedstring

Can anyone tell me how can i have english set as my region but call the russian localizable.string based on what the user has put in the application preferences (this is also implemented by me and stored in NSUserDefaults).

I want the user to be in control of what language the application should use on launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ru", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Apparently this will do it if you put it in the init method of your application.